# Do not understand error with packagegroup

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Building our image produces this error, which is recorded in **yocto-nsdk-ip-image-swu/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs**. (layout modified for clarity)

```
ERROR: Unable to install packages. 
Command '/home/jbrown/develop/source/gitmore/MRXx40-build-yocto/work/mrx40-poky-linux/yocto-nsdk-ip-image-swu/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/opkg 
--volatile-cache 
-f /home/jbrown/develop/source/gitmore/MRXx40-build-yocto/work/mrx40-poky-linux/yocto-nsdk-ip-image-swu/1.0-r0/opkg.conf 
-t /home/jbrown/develop/source/gitmore/MRXx40-build-yocto/work/mrx40-poky-linux/yocto-nsdk-ip-image-swu/1.0-r0/temp/ipktemp/ 
-o /home/jbrown/develop/source/gitmore/MRXx40-build-yocto/work/mrx40-poky-linux/yocto-nsdk-ip-image-swu/1.0-r0/rootfs  
--force_postinstall --prefer-arch-to-version   --force-maintainer --force-overwrite install 
alsa-utils-amixer alsa-utils-aplay automated-build-version avahi-autoipd curl dleyna-connector-dbus dleyna-server factory-tool 
gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-aiff gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-bluez 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-inter gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-mms gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-mpegtsdemux gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-sbc gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-adder gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-alsa 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-audioconvert gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-audiorate gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-audioresample gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-audiotestsrc gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-encoding 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-opus gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-playback gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-rawparse gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-tcp gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-typefindfunctions 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-volume gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-apetag gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-autodetect gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-debug gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-icydemux 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-id3demux gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-level gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-mpg123 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-multifile gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-multipart 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-rtp gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-rtpmanager gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-souphttpsrc gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-udp gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-wavenc gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-wavparse 
iperf2 iw log4cplus mtd-utils mtd-utils-ubifs mwifiex-testmodes ntfs-3g opensource-codecs-meta opkg 
packagegroup-base-extended packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-core-ssh-dropbear 
procps psplash rsync run-postinsts streamapp udev-extraconf util-linux-blkid' returned 1:
Collected errors:
 * Solver encountered 1 problem(s):
 * Problem 1/1:
 *   - nothing provides embeddedwebui needed by packagegroup-machine-base-1.0-r83.mrx40
 * 
 * Solution 1:
 *   - do not ask to install a package providing packagegroup-base-extended
```

`embeddwebui` is our recipe for a directory tree of static web files.

I cannot find a recipe tying `embeddedwebui` and `packagegroup-machine-base` together. I do not understand why `packagegroup-machine-base` needs to know about `embeddedwebui`. Where would I connect them?

Comment: Can you check in deploy/ipk directory if embeddedwebui* exists ? I am  guessing this package is empty and thusly deleted by package manager. you can also try adding ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1" in your recipe and see if it starts to work. If it does then it means the packaging part of your recipe needs to put contents into embeddedwebui via FILES_${PN} ..

Comment: OK, that's helps get it to build the image, but without answering the question. I still cannot move from FILES_${PN} to adding files to the image through do_install().

Comment: what more explaining do you need? embeddedwebui is an empty package which is added to runtime dependencies perhaps via packagegroup packagegroup-machine-base and empty packages are removed bt default by packager. Therefore when its building image it does not find a package called embeddedwebui. When you add ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1" you are basically telling the build system that even if the package is empty please create it and don't delete it.

Comment: Looking at the recipe for packagegroup-machine-base it looks like uses MACHINE_EXTRA_RDEPENDS and MACHINE_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS, so maybe it's in your machine configuration and not in a recipe?

Comment: You rmain issue seems to be the empty package though, and I don't understand the "I still cannot move from FILES_${PN} to adding files to the image through do_install()" comment? You need to install the files using do_install() AND use FILES_${PN} so specify which files should be included. It's not one or the other.